# Hosting solution for images for website written in PHP

Tags: php, image, hosting, storage, cdn

I've written a website in PHP and it will have ability for users to upload images. My website will have more than 100.000 users. Aprox. 1k users will upload image about 50 KB. And every image will be displayed on this website 5k times so it's transfer of:

1k x 50 KB x 5k = 250 GB per month.

So my question is:

Do you know any good solution (hosting or CDN network or else) that:

- will be payed for transfer not space used and no entrance fee
- will have API to upload images easily with PHP
- is extremely easy to use
- will be good for low budget
- will not require any special, complicated registration and formal things
- will allow commercial use
- will allow using this images in website layout

?

Comment: @Sabeen Malik - I went to their website, and could not find this solution, can you provide me a direct link?

Comment: "What’s the best CDN for image hosting on a high-volume web site?"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369/whats-the-best-cdn-for-image-hosting-on-a-high-volume-web-site

Comment: there is no special solution that you need,you can get their cloud site account, host your site there and it will scale automatically according to the traffic. as far as storage goes, from the calculations your images wont need alot of space 1000 * 50 = 50,000k.... so u get the site hosting + storage and if your CPU usage increases (due to images or site traffic) you get charged according to usage. Talk to their tech support, they are very helpful.

Comment: @Sabeen Malik Ok, it's a solution. But thus I would like to find something dedicated for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna make my comment into a proper answer.

From what i see the image storage is probably trivial compared to the site traffic and application load. So you use the cloud sites from Rack Space for your PHP application and pay for extra CPU usage according to traffic, application load. If you need specialized solution for storage you can use Cloud Files as an addon and the integration should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I don't want any space for my PHP app but for images. Is there any special offer at Rack Space for this kind of need?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 nearly meets those requirements.

I think the only one it fails on is that it has a storage charge (a small one) in addition to a bandwidth charge.

Comment: do you think that I can do it in 15 minutes on Amazon S3?

Comment: I have no idea what your technical proficiency is … but it is rare to find a service that you can sign up for (including providing billing information), learn an API for it, and implement an application that uses that API in 15 minutes.

Comment: @David Dorward It's rare, but possible - true. So David , what do you think - how long will it take to implement this functionality at Amazon S3?

Comment: I still have no idea how difficult integrating with your code would be, and I still have no idea what level of technical expertise you have. I'm not going to make time estimates!

Comment: @David Dorward I'm a developer for like 9 years now and all I need to do now is to put simple plain PHP code that uploads file to hosting solution without any integration with my existing code. Is this enough info for you to estimate time?

Comment: No, it isn't. Look at the API. Look at what libraries are available for PHP. Estimate based on your own experiences.

Comment: @David Dorward Oh, ok. I have now a feeling that it will take days to learn and start using this solution to my problem if you can't give straight answer to this question with all info you wanted to know and I think you used Amazon S3 and have some experience to make some estimates. Does Amazon S3 have something similar to Cloud Files at Rack Space ?

Comment: I seem to have accidentally implied that with more information I could estimate how long it would take you to do something. I'll rephrase — given lots of data, it is hard to estimate how long it will take someone you know and have worked with to do something. It is much much harder when you don't know the person and don't have lots of data.

Comment: I have no idea if S3 has anything like Cloud Files, I don't know what Cloud Files are.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Azure Cloud](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/)

Comment: Is it worth to learn this big big thing only to do one tiny image hosting?

Comment: @tomaszs Nothing big there. Similar to amazon. Simple API to store files and that is it really :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @netcoder it's a third party service. Any description I include in my answer will be obsolete in a month. Clicking on links got to be easier than complaining about answers!